# How can all postfix alerts to root be disabled?

Tags: email, postfix

I've recently installed Postfix on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using a gmail account to send messages from it.
From time to time I get delivery failure messages to root@mydomain.com. The title of those messages is:

```
*** SECURITY information for myhost
```

The content was one time related to unresolved host; another time an incorrect password attempt for a sudo command.

How can all these types of messages can be turned off? Is it possible to make all messages with root@mydomain.com recipient be ignored by Postfix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit `/etc/aliases` file and change the line with *postmaster* to something like:

```
postmaster: /dev/null
```

This will redirect every mail to *postmaster* to the trash. It could be better to redirect it to a local file instead of trashing them. Look at your option in [man page of aliases](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html)

After you have made your change to `/etc/aliases`, run

```
newaliases
postfix reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Your system writing security alerts and postfix sending them on to you indicates that something is wrong. Simply sending these alerts to /dev/null is going to hide genuine security issues. In this case you will have a security problem, probably being send when someone attempts to log in. The fix is to check through your auth.log to see what is triggering these messages (search for "problem" - `grep problem /var/log/auth.log`) and work out why before fixing it.